# How to remove duplicate images in pygame while moving

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

How to remove this duplicate of balloon while moving

[image]

Here's my code

```
lead_x = 0
lead_y = 400
balloonR_x = 400
balloonR_y = 400
balloonP_x = 500
balloonP_y = 400
balloonR_move = 50
#balloonB_x = 550
#balloonB_Y = 400

lead_y_change = 0 

gameExit = False



while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change += 10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            lead_y_change = 0



    lead_y += lead_y_change
    gamedisplay.blit(bg, [0,0])
    gamedisplay.blit(bow,[lead_x, lead_y])
    while balloonR_y >= 50:
        gamedisplay.blit(red_balloon, [balloonR_x, balloonR_y])
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.event.clear(balloonR_y)
        clock.tick(1)
        balloonR_y -= balloonR_move
    #gamedisplay.blit(red_balloon, [balloonR_x, balloonR_y])
    gamedisplay.blit(purple_balloon, [balloonP_x, balloonP_y])
    #gamedisplay.blit(blue_balloon, [balloonB_x, balloonB_y])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(20)
```

and also if i run the program first the balloon loop gets executed first in that time i cannot able to control the arrow.

Comment: you can't use `while balloonR_y >= 50` because this way you doesn't blit background which remove older image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `while` loop (and any long-running functions or `sleep()`).

You have to only change baloon position and let main `while` blits background and other elements (and does other things like handle events, make other animations, etc.)

More or less:

```
while not gameExit:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change += 10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            lead_y_change = 0

    # --- updates (without draws) ---

    lead_y += lead_y_change

    if balloonR_y >= 50:
        balloonR_y -= balloonR_move

    # --- draws (without updates) ---

    gamedisplay.blit(bg, [0,0])
    gamedisplay.blit(bow,[lead_x, lead_y])

    gamedisplay.blit(red_balloon, [balloonR_x, balloonR_y])

    gamedisplay.blit(purple_balloon, [balloonP_x, balloonP_y])
    #gamedisplay.blit(blue_balloon, [balloonB_x, balloonB_y])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(20)
```